# How long does it take to reach a decision after "Pending Decision Approval" status?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I have a paper that was under review with one of Wiley's journals. The paper received an R&R last summer and a revised version was provided. The status of the paper has since changed from "Under Review" to "Decision Pending", and recently, maybe 4 days ago, the status has changed to "Decision Pending Approval". My understanding is that the editor has made the decision based on the reviews, but they have now passed the decision to the editor-in-chief.

My query is how long this process of "Decision Pending Approval" normally takes?

Comment: So many people would be much less anxious if they just stopped refreshing the author page on journals.

Comment: @henning yes, it provides a sketchy idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to tell.

Check with Journal, they usually provide statistics as to what is their average decision time. In case they don't, it won't hurt to ask these numbers.

If they are well past their normal decision times, you should inquire about your submission status. Since they seem to be updating, albeit slowly, I would consider you to enhance your patience.